# Are cells of 4-polytopes a convex polyhedron by definition?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, computational-geometry, polytopes

I'm going by the [Wikipedia definition for a 4-polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4-polytope#Definition).

Do by definition, cells of 4-polytopes have to be a convex polyhedra?

If not, then are there polyhedra with non-convex faces?
If yes, is it the same for all dimensions? For example, if I have a d-dimensional polytope, does it imply that his facets are d-1-dimensional convex polytopes? (Where the definition of convex polytopes is: the convex hull of a finite amount of vertices)

Comment: See [Kepler–Poinsot polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%E2%80%93Poinsot_polyhedron) and [Uniform polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_polyhedron) for plenty of non-convex polyhedron. Also in the combinatorial sense, there is no reason to igore polytopes with non-convex cells.

Comment: For a simple example, take any non-convex polygon and a [prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism_(geometry)) over it, it its higher dimensional analogues. So yes, this happens in all dimensions at least 3.

Comment: The cells of a convex polytope have to be convex themselves (since each is a convex hull of a subset of the original finite set of vertices). You can certainly restrict attention to convex polytopes. But if your polytope is not convex, then its cells don't have to be convex either.